# Using JavaScript modules in external files

Tags: javascript, jquery, module

I have a skeleton of a module which adds a record to a database with a button click.

```
var Person = (function () {
    var ajaxOpts = {
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () { },
        error: function () { },
        data: {}
    }
    function insert(data) {
        ajaxOpts.url = "../Service.asmx/InsertPerson";
        ajaxOpts.data = JSON.stringify(data);
        ajaxOpts.error = function (xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.status);

        };
        ajaxOpts.success = function (data) {
            console.log('record successfully added');
            console.log(data.d);

        }
        $.ajax(ajaxOpts);
    };
    return {
        insert: insert
    }
} ());
```

and I call it from my webpage like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                var data = {
                    personId: $('#personId').val(),
                    firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
                    lastName: $('#lastName').val()
                };
                Person.insert(data);
            });
        });
```

How can I modify this code to make sure that `$` is the jQuery object and not another library?

Comment: In both files or where exactly?

Comment: Let's say both files are loaded with a CDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plugins you usually wrap the code in an IIFE and map `jQuery` to `$`. You could do the same for your module (you even already have an IIFE):

```
var Person = (function($) {
    // ...
}(jQuery));
```

For `document.ready` callbacks, a reference to jQuery is passed to the callback:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // ...
});
```

Just make sure that you are using `jQuery` outside of the functions.

Comment: So all I really need to do is change my IIFE like you have it their in your first code block?  What makes that work?  I think it takes whatever parameters is passed to it and returns jQuery?  I guess this works because I'm calling Person methods inside of jQuery?

Comment: *"What makes that work?"* I'm not sure what you mean. You pass `jQuery` as argument to the function and name the parameter `$`. So any use of `$` inside the function refers to the parameter and not to the global `$`. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: I worded that poorly, let's say I was using another library that used $ besides jQuery, how do those objects not collide and mess up (doesn't prototype use $ as well?)

Comment: Well, inside the function, `$` will refer to jQuery then. It will *shadow* the global `$` variable. If you also want to be able to access the other library, you could use `$j` instead of `$` to access jQuery and `$` to access the other library.

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing code in your main page like this:

```
(function($) {
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        var data = {
            personId: $('#personId').val(),
            firstName: $('#firstName').val(),
            lastName: $('#lastName').val()
        };
        Person.insert(data);
    });
}(jQuery));
```